# Laravel Carbon changes the time, but not the date based on timezone

Tags: php, laravel

When I create a payment it gets stored in the database with UTC time.

```
# id, paymentrequest_id, name, note, currency, amount, created_at, updated_at
3, 1, Test, test, Euro (€), 10.00, 2019-03-29 14:27:15, 2019-03-29 14:27:15
```

When I load the page with my timezone (Europe/Amsterdam) I see the correct time (GMT+1).

```
2019-03-29 15:27:15
```

But it should be formatted as `29-03-2019 15:27:15`

When I connect to the USA (NYC) with a VPN. It shows me this.

```
2019-03-29 10:27:15
```

It's the correct time, but the date should be `03-29-2019`

**This is the code I use**

```
$ip = file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain");
$url = 'http://ip-api.com/json/'.$ip;
$tz = file_get_contents($url);
$tz = json_decode($tz,true)['timezone'];

foreach ($payments as $payment)
{
    $payment->created_at = Carbon::parse($payment->created_at)->timezone($tz)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution I could use, first time I'm using Carbon.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Date formats are always Y-m-d unless you specify differently.

Comment: @aynber How would I change this based on timezone?

Comment: Timezone makes no difference. The definition for `toDateTimeString()` just returns `return $this->rawFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s');` (See [the source code](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/ba07badf09dadcba9b627764e4a5400b16df3a69/src/Carbon/Traits/Converter.php))  You can try `formatLocalized()` or `isoFormat()`, but that's based on locale, not the timezone. (See [Localization](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization))

Comment: did you tried `$date->setTimezone($tz);` right before `$payment->created_at` looks like you're setting up dynamic timezone to created_date so i think you need to set timezone first